# Problems with first OFX transaction download to gnucash after using Quicken for years

Tags: gnucash, ofx

I have been using Quicken for home and business for years to keep my one man office books.  It does everything I need, especially auto-population of bank transactions in register for preparing financial statements.

Now converting to GnuCash and used the wizard to a) import to gnu from Quicken data file, then b) set up OFX transaction download from bank directly to gnu.  Got data import great, but efforts to get OFX duds.

I am a retired dba so I kind of know what I'm doing, but didn't help much.  I called the bank and worked with a tech person there but didn't get anywhere with her either.  I kept getting the error that there were no new transactions to download since the last one, which was 3 weeks and 29 transactions ago.

Am I going to just have to download CSV monthly and import to gnu or can I actually get OFX to work?